# Wacom Tablet Weird interaction with Manga Studios

Tags: drivers, tablet, wacom

I installed Manga Studios 5EX with WINE, the application seems to be working fine.

I used source forge to get drivers for my Intuos 4 Tablet, and although the Tablet settings options are very different from the windows version, and some aspects of the tablets physical button interface are different, it all seems to be working. I can use the tablet in place of my mouse and I can set the buttons and scroll wheel to do what I want.

My problem comes when I open Manga Studios 5, and it is a very strange problem. When I use my normal mouse everything in MS5 works normally, I can draw (without pressure sensitivity) but I checked most of the features and WINE seems to have handled the installation well. Everything seems to work fine with the mouse. The tablet, at first seems to also work in MS5, I can use it to select a pen or pencil change colors and open a new page to draw on. However the Pen does not work in the Canvas area of the page. When I move my pen such that the cursor would enter the Canvas area, the cursor simply disappears. If I make it all the way to the other side of the Canvas area, to the far right side where the screen space is used by more menus, my cursor reappears and works normally. If I try to draw in an area with the cursor while using the pen nothing happens, I can switch to the mouse and draw on the canvas but for some reason the Pen and Tablet seem to only work on the menu portions of the application.

Sadly I am a very new Ubuntu users and I can't provide more information than this. Honestly unless someone else has had this exact same problem I doubt anyone will have a solution but here is hoping.

In the mean time I am trying to get CS6 up an running to test the tablet in a different application that is also pressure sensitive. I used the Gnome paint tool and my tablet worked fine, but it was not pressure sensitive and I suspect the problem might have something to do with the pen and tablet not working when they are supposed to display pressure sensitivity.

EDIT: In case anyone ever has this problem, there seems to be an option under File Preferences in Manga Studios 5 Checking the box for C ordinate mode or Tablet control area both seem to make the pen work on the Canvas with pressure sensitivity. So far I am experiencing some glitchyness with the pen, the cursor seems to skip around a lot but I can't actually tell if this is effecting my ability to draw with it or not, I will play with these settings to see if it gets better. In any case if anyone ever has this problem, then the solution might be to change these settings in Manga studio.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Manga Studio EX 5, under File/Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>), find "Tablet" on the left side and click it, then click "Tablet PC" instead of "Wintab" or whatever else it says for your setup. This worked for me. Thanks Ashton for the updated info.

Answer (score 1):

I found doing it on windows that sometimes the windows choose the Wintab instead of the tablet PC and that has been known to be faulty so

Try do the following

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>
Changes it from the Wintab to Tablet PC.
In my case it unstuck the pen.

Answer (score 0):

Changing undo to some other hotkey helps a little. I figured that as soon I use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, as for undo, the cursor starts to flicker and acting weird. The behaviour turns to normal when I <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to another application and back.

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried doing the ctrl+k thing and when I hit TabletPC, it worked but  the pen line wasn't smooth anymore and it didn't detect my pen pressure (a definite NO for my professional manga that I am attempting).  So, instead, I tried something random that fixed everything for me.  I left it on WinTab, but I checked the box just beneath it "Use mouse mode in setting of tablet driver(Z)" and then it fixed everything perfectly including the no pen issue, jagged line issue, and the pressure issue.

So I would say hit ctrl+k but check the box beneath wintab instead of hitting TabletPC